# Is my sentence sounding formal?

Tags: grammar, american-english, formality, north-american-english

I am having difficulties in describing a situation where there have been two lab tests A and B and where I receive two results without indicating which belongs to A and which to B.

Can I ask: "Could you please tell me in the two lab results which belongs to which?" (which belongs to A and which belongs to B)

How do I say it properly? Please help !!

Comment: You need some way of identifying the results first. Let's hope they have say identification numbers. "Could you kindly inform me whether result XZ7325/47a relates to test A or test B. Thank you."

Comment: Please tell me which result belongs to which test?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is looking for content (what to say).

Answer (score 1):

I would say it like this:

Please indicate which test each result belongs to.